# Why is the first rowspan not working?

Tags: html

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>table</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table border = "1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan = "6">Home Ticket Options</th>
                <th>Zone</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Red</td>
                <td>$101.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Blue</td>
                <td rowspan = "2">25.50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Green</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yellow</td>
                <td rowspan = "2">$9.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Orange</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

The last 2 rowspans are stretching down 2 rows as they should, but the first rowspan is not stretching down 6 rows.  Any ideas on what I did wrong?
Please help.

Comment: I just loaded your HTML code in Chrome, and it looks fine.  Why would you want the `rowspan` for **Home Ticket Options** to span 6 rows?

Comment: It does load, but I need it to show as one big cell.

Answer (score 0):

That because you use `rowspan="6"` in `<thead>` table header, that you can't. You have to use `rowspan="5"` in `<tbody>` table body first row. That work all five rows in a table.

### View this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vafonebimu/1/edit?html,output)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>table</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table border = "1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Home Ticket Options</th>
                <th>Zone</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan = "5">Price</td>
                <td>Red</td>
                <td>$101.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Blue</td>
                <td rowspan = "2">25.50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Green</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yellow</td>
                <td rowspan = "2">$9.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Orange</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That puts price under home ticket sales & I just need home ticket sales to make one big cell that stretches down through everything.

Comment: if you move zone to the first cell then rowspan cell come to second that means 2nd column all five rows merge into one.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  I figured it out.  I have to put it all in tbody & then rowspan the cell.  Thank you everybody.